# Javascript If statement then continue

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

I'm running an if statement and checking a date different with momentjs. How would I stop the entire function execution if the statement is true, then inside that decide whether to continue the whole function or exit?

For example, I have a function called store

```
$(document).on('click', '#new-booking-form input[type="submit"]', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    //If the difference in months is more than 3
    if(moment($('input[name="my_input"]').val() , 'DD/MM/YYYY').diff(moment(), 'months') > 3){
            swal({
                title: 'Warning',
                html: 'The starting date you have selected is more than 3 months in the future, is this correct?',
                type: 'warning',
                customClass: 'swal-logout',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonText: 'Yes'
            }).then((result) => {
                if (result.value) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
    }



   //Do the submit here
})
```

The way I need this function work is

- If the if statement is false, run the rest of the function.
- If the if statement is true, prompt the user, if the user selects yes, run the rest of the function.
- If the if statement is true, prompt the user, if the user selects no, return false and do not run the function.

How do I hold of running an entire function based on the `if` statement and then if the user selects yes or no?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is what you're looking for, but it sounds like you're trying to forcefully resolve the promise

```
function errorHandler(error) {
  throw(error)
};

if(moment($('input[name="my_input"]').val() , 'DD/MM/YYYY').diff(moment(), 'months') > 3){
        swal({
            title: 'Warning',
            html: 'The starting date you have selected is more than 3 months in the future, is this correct?',
            type: 'warning',
            customClass: 'swal-logout',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes'
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.value) {
                return true;
            }
        }, errorHandler);
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: I'm basically looking for it to pause the whole function if the if statement is true, then wait for a response of true or false from the user